# WPF User Control is not recognized in XAML page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I created a WPF user control ,for multi select combo box with checkboxes and search option .However when i try to access it in a XAML page ,the intellisense in Page tag of XAML does not show my user control .I have build my solution the User control is in a folder called CustomControls in VMS3 namespace

```
xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:VMS3.CustomControls"
```

I tried using this tag in my xaml after typing the namespace manually

```
<local2:MultiSelectComboBox></local2:MultiSelectComboBox>
```

But i get the error "The type multiselectcombobox was not found ,Verify that you are not missing any assembly reference"

This is my xaml code in User control

```
<UserControl x:Class="VMS3.CustomControls.MultiSelectComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="35" d:DesignWidth="162">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox    x:Name="MultiSelectComboCheckBox"  Style="{StaticResource md-2s-combo }"  VerticalAlignment="top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                     SelectionChanged="MultiSelectComboBox_SelectionChanged"  DataContextChanged="MultiSelectComboBox_DataContextChanged"
                                     TextBoxBase.TextChanged="MultiSelectComboBox_TextChanged"  IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True"   IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"    >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="chkbox" Width="220" Checked="Chkbox_Checked"  Unchecked="Chkbox_Unchecked"  Content="{Binding VALUE}" IsChecked="{Binding STATUS,Mode=TwoWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding KEY}"  >
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My code behind .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace VMS3.CustomControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MultiSelectComboBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MultiSelectComboBox : UserControl
    {
        public DataTable ldtDetails = new DataTable();
        public MultiSelectComboBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void MultiSelectComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MultiSelectComboCheckBox.SelectedValue = "";
                MultiSelectComboCheckBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void MultiSelectComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MultiSelectComboCheckBox.Text == "System.Data.DataRowView")
                {
                    MultiSelectComboCheckBox.Text = "";
                    MultiSelectComboCheckBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
                    return;
                }

                DataTable ldtDetail = new DataTable();

                if (ldtDetails.Select("VALUE LIKE '%" + MultiSelectComboCheckBox.Text.ToString().Trim() + "%'").Count() > 0)
                {


                    MultiSelectComboCheckBox.ItemsSource = ldtDetails.Select("VALUE LIKE '%" + MultiSelectComboCheckBox.Text.ToString().Trim() + "%'").CopyToDataTable().DefaultView;
                    MultiSelectComboCheckBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;

                }



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void Chkbox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox clickedBox = (CheckBox)sender;

            for (int liRow = 0; liRow <= ldtDetails.Rows.Count - 1; liRow++)
            {
                if (clickedBox.Content == ldtDetails.Rows[liRow]["VALUE"].ToString().Trim())
                {
                    ldtDetails.Rows[liRow]["STATUS"] = true;
                }
            }
            MultiSelectComboCheckBox.ItemsSource = ldtDetails.DefaultView;
        }

        private void Chkbox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox clickedBox = (CheckBox)sender;

            for (int liRow = 0; liRow <= ldtDetails.Rows.Count - 1; liRow++)
            {
                if (clickedBox.Content == ldtDetails.Rows[liRow]["VALUE"].ToString().Trim())
                {
                    ldtDetails.Rows[liRow]["STATUS"] = false;
                }
            }
            MultiSelectComboCheckBox.ItemsSource = ldtDetails.DefaultView;
        }

        private void MultiSelectComboBox_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ldtDetails = (DataTable)this.DataContext;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your custom control in the same assembly? If not, you have to set explicitly the assembly too (for example: "xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:VMS3.CustomControls;assembly=MyAssembly"
")

Comment: Yes,it is in same assembly

Comment: Have you tried rebuild? Does it  success?

Comment: I closed and restarted Visual studio and it is working ,the user control works but in the XAML design view ,there is like a yellow exclamation mark on the user control